# How to write maximum function in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Here's my code but it doesn't seem to work. I don't know why...

```
Function maximum()
Dim i As Integer
Dim dernLigne As Long
Dim somme as Variant
somme = 0
lastLigne = Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row
Range("C65536").Value = valuemax
i = 2
While i <= lastLigne
    If Range("C" & i).Value > valeurmax Then
        valuemax = Range("C" & i).Value
        i = i + 1
    End If
Wend
maximum = valeurmax
End Function
```

Thanks

Comment: You have a typo.  In two places you are using `valeurmax` while in others you are using `valuemax`.  and this line `Range("C65536").Value = valuemax` will not work if you are calling this function from the worksheet.  Also it will always be `0` as at that time `valuemax` is nothing.

Comment: Why not use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Max()`? (Or just `Max()` itself if you are calling it from the worksheet).

Comment: A UDF cannot write to the worksheet; e.g. `Range("C65536").Value = valuemax`. Use Application.Max(...) or MAX(...) on the worksheet as suggested by @JohnColeman.

Comment: @John Coleman No, I have  to it's an assignment Scott Craner Yes. I wanted to translate but failed

Comment: Why to write a custom function when there is buitl-in function that does the same? The bye other hand, questions about "why this code doesn't work" should follow the guidelines of [mcve]: "Tell us what the **exact wording of the error message is**, and which line of code is producing it".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two functions for your consideration:

```
Option Explicit

Function maxFixedRange() As Double

Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
For i = 2 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    If IsNumeric(ws.Cells(i, 3).Value2) Then
        If ws.Cells(i, 3).Value2 > maxFixedRange Then
            maxFixedRange = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value2
        End If
    End If
Next i

End Function
```

---

```
Function maxVariableRange(rng As Range) As Double

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In rng
    If IsNumeric(cell.Value2) Then
        If cell.Value2 > maxVariableRange Then
            maxVariableRange = cell.Value2
        End If
    End If
Next cell

End Function
```

The first function looks for the maximum in a **fixed range**. That means that you cannot look for the maximum in a different range with that function.

The second function is expecting a range of cells. All of the cells in that range will be taken into consideration when looking for the maximum value.

[image]